# How does the Implementation of System Calls and Interrupts differ from each other?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-16

I am developing a simple Operating System only to know its internals better. On developing a `Boot loader` and a simple kernel that runs on `16-bit Real Mode`, I came across the unfamiliar term `System Call` and a familiar `Interrupt`.

I have been Googling the terms since only to find that the concepts are still unclear to me. As far as I have understood, the System calls are used by the Application programs running in `least privileged mode` to request for a service to the Kernel running in `Higher Privileged mode(Ring 0)`.

I am still unclear of How the System Calls are implemented.

Say, I am writing a Simple C program to `print a word` and compiling it. Now, I am left with an executable file that contains a System Call to print the given word on screen. My questions corresponding to the given scenario are as follows:

**Question 1:**

As soon the Program is executed, the system call informs the kernel of the request - What exactly happens here in terms of low level programming?

**Question 2:**

Can an Interrupt be a System Call or vice versa?

---

If it seems that I have not understood the concepts clearly, Kindly explain me the Concept of System Call.

---

Thanking you.

Comment: Note that you don't have privilege levels in real mode. System call is a generic term for invoking the OS. An interrupt can be used to execute a system call, but x86 also has specialized instructions for that (`syscall`, `sysenter`).

Comment: Does that mean System call and Interrupts are the same?

Comment: No they are not the same. Interrupts can be used to implement system calls, but that's not their primary purpose.

Comment: In particular, "software interrupts" can be used to implement system calls. For example, MS-DOS and PC BIOS use them extensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most systems, interrupts and system calls (and exception handlers) are implemented in the same way.

> As soon the Program is executed, the system call informs the kernel of the request - What exactly happens here in terms of low level programming?

Usually, system calls are wrappers around assembly language routines. The sequence of events is:

1. Call to System Routine
2. System Routine unpacks parameters and loads them into registers.
3. System Routine forces an exception (identified by a number) by executing a change mode instruction (to some mode higher than user mode).
4. The CPU handles the exception by dispatching to an exception handler in the system dispatch table.
5. The handler performs the system service.
6. The handler executes a return from exception or interrupt instruction, returning the process to user mode (or whatever mode was called from) and to the system service routine.
7. The system service routine unpacks the return values from registers and updates the parameters.
8. Return to the calling function.

> Can an Interrupt be a System Call or vice versa?

No. They are dispatched in the same way.

Presumably an operating system could map system calls and interrupts to the same handler but that would be screwy.

Answer (score 2):

System Calls are like function calls to the operating system, that perform operations that cannot or should not be handled manually by the programs and fall in the task scope of the operating system, e.g. file manipulation, writing to screen etc.

The x86 handles handles interrupts by some kind of callback mechanism. All kinds of external interrupt are given an interrupt number. The operating system sets up a table, (the interrupt vector table in real mode and the interrupt descriptor table in protected mode), that stores pointers to functions that handle the corresponding interrupt. For example if the pressing a key interrupt would be assigned to `int 21h` upon receiving the interrupt from the interrupt controller, the CPU stores the current code segment, instruction pointer, flags and stack and then the CPU will examine entry 21h in the interrupt table and reads out the address where the instruction handler is located. It then executes the handler and resumes normal execution.

However this behavior of calling an handler in the interrupt table can not only be triggered by real hardware interrupts, but also by an internal exception (like divide by zero, reaching an undefined opcode, etc.). The exceptions are assigned to interrupt numbers that are hopefully different to the ones used by hardware interrupts.

Finally any interrupt can also be triggered directly by the currently executed program using the "int n" instruction.

This last feature is often used for system calls. The reason is that the user program only needs to know the interrupt number (witch is usually standardized (DOS uses mainly 21h, Linux mainly 80h) and the operation system can located the interrupt handler wherever it likes it to be and store its address in the the corresponding interrupt table entry.

Keep in mind that there are other ways to implement system calls. For example in protected mode the x86 provides call gates witch are special segments that cause a system call if your try to load them into CS using a far call. Newer processors provide special syscall instructions that are faster them interrupts